# CloudKit dashboard access for free developer account added to an existing Individual Apple Developer Program team

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, cloudkit, apple-developer-account, cloudkit-environments

I created a new Gmail address for CloudKit testing purposes only, and invited this address to join my team on [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users). I see the new account in the "Developer" part of the Users page.

[image]

But when I try to add this new user on the container permission on the CloudKit dashboard, I only see me (my main owner account) and not the developer email address I just created.

[image]

Can free developer account added to an Individual Apple Developer Program team access a CloudKit dashboard? I really need this to test my app and see records in the private database (log the new user on the Simulator and a device to test sync is working, etc.).

Comment: Have you been able to fix this issue? I am the very same situation.

Comment: Any Updates on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done. Make sure that the new account has been fully set up as an Apple ID.

Usually this process isn't final until you sign it at [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com) with the new account and accept any terms and conditions.

Once that is done, try signing into the CloudKit Dashboard again and see if the name appears. If it doesn't, try re-inviting that email from the developer portal.

Comment: I did what you suggested but still can’t see this invited user... I received the invitation email from Apple, I sign in with the invited account, accept terms. From the primary account, I see the secondary accepted and joined the team but don’t see it in CloudKit dashboard... 

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, then. Maybe submit Feedback to Apple.

Comment: Won't fix the problem for me too. Super annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I have a paid developer account, I had the same issue that other team members weren't shown in the list in CloudKit Dashboard.

So I asked Apple about this. Apple said team members need to have access to Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles.

After giving my team member access to Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles, they immediately appeared in the CloudKit Dashboard.

Hope this might help other fellow developers, too.